# Do not want variable name to be set by a string

Tags: r

In the following R code, if I want to pull and analyze data for a symbol other than SPY, I need to replace both the string "SPY" and the variable name SPY.
How can I write the code so that the ticker symbol is set in only one place?

```
library("quantmod")
getSymbols("SPY", from = '1990-01-01')
print(summary(monthly.prices <- Ad(SPY)[endpoints(SPY, on = 'months')]))
sym = "SPY"
# line below does not work
print(summary(monthly.prices <- Ad(sym)[endpoints(sym, on = 'months')]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run `getSymbols`, it's generating a warning that I don't fully understand (I also have no idea what that specific function is supposed to do), but I don't think it's relevant to the core of your question.

Two options...

**Option 1**

`eval(parse(text = x))` will evaluate the character `x` as an expression. That is to say, it is equivalent to to replacing that bit of code with whatever the value of `x` is at run time.

```
library("quantmod")
sym <- "SPY"
getSymbols(sym, from = '1990-01-01')
q1 <- summary(Ad(SPY)[endpoints(SPY, on = 'months')])
xts_obj <- eval(parse(text = sym))
q2 <- summary(Ad(xts_obj)[endpoints(xts_obj, on = 'months')])
print(all(q1==q2))
```

**Option 2**

This is cleaner, but only works because of `getSymbols` default functionality can be overridden via the `auto.assign` parameter. If the function always made a `<<-` style assignment then the best you could do is create a wrapper function

```
library("quantmod")
sym <- "SPY"
getSymbols(sym, from = '1990-01-01', auto.assign = T)
q1 <- summary(Ad(SPY)[endpoints(SPY, on = 'months')])
q2 <- getSymbols(sym, from = '1990-01-01', auto.assign = F)
print(all(q1==q2))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write a function that takes the ticker symbol as input.  Note that setting `auto.assign  = FALSE` in `getSymbols()` allows us to assign any variable name (here I call it `dat`) directly.  Then we use `dat` throughout the function.  This way you can also run other symbols easily, without having to change anything in the code.

```
symFun <- function(sym) {
    dat <- getSymbols(sym, from = "1990-01-01", auto.assign = FALSE)
    monthly.prices <- Ad(dat)[endpoints(dat, on = "months")]
    summary(monthly.prices)
}

symFun("SPY")
#     Index             SPY.Adjusted   
# Min.   :1993-01-29   Min.   : 28.60  
# 1st Qu.:1998-11-06   1st Qu.: 70.31  
# Median :2004-08-15   Median : 95.23  
# Mean   :2004-08-14   Mean   : 97.93  
# 3rd Qu.:2010-05-21   3rd Qu.:117.27  
# Max.   :2016-02-19   Max.   :208.17
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a variable `symbol = "SPY"`, and then use `eval(parse(text=symbol))` to call the actual variable. Mind you, it's probably not good practice, and hard to read / maintain down the line.